# Installing Pi-Hole on Raspberry Pi OS via Windows: port 22: Connection refused

Tags: windows, raspberry-pi-os, pi-hole, curl

I've installed Raspberry OS on a MicroSD via the Windows installer downloaded [here](https://www.raspberrypi.org/software/).

I then used [this tutorial](https://github.com/pi-hole/pi-hole/#one-step-automated-install).

However, when I try `curl -sSL https://install.pi-hole.net | bash` via the Windows command prompt (that I run as Administrator) I get the error:

> curl: (23) Failed writing body (2691 != 16384)

How can I install Pi-Hole via Windows 10?

**UPDATE 1**
I tried connecting via SSH, like so:
`ssh pi@192.168.178.103`

I get the error:

> ssh: connect to host 192.168.178.103 port 22: Connection refused

I then checked [this post](https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=210137) which states that I need to enable SSH on the Pi by placing a ssh file in the `BOOT` folder; however using Windows Explorer I cannot access the SD card anymore (needs to be formatted first).

So then I looked [here](https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/remote-access/ssh/).
Option 1 is "Launch Raspberry Pi Configuration" (no idea how I can do that)
Option 2 is run `sudo raspi-config`, however sudo is [not available](https://support.circleci.com/hc/en-us/articles/360045816254-How-to-sudo-on-Powershell-Windows-executor) in Windows Powershell, and `Start-Process raspi-config` cannot find the file specified.

So I'm stuck now. How can I enable SSH on my Rasperberry Pi (which runs Raspberry Pi OS) so I can install Pi-Hole?

**UPDATE 2**

Found the `BOOT` disk and placed an empty `ssh.txt` file on it. I reattempted to connect via SSH `ssh pi@192.168.178.103` but get the same error:

> ssh: connect to host 192.168.178.103 port 22: Connection refused

Comment: The card has a windows readable partition and a linux partition so you can put the SD card in your PC and ignore the message about needing to format it.  You will see a new drive called BOOT - put the ssh file on this, eject the card and try again.  The raspi-config program (and the sudo command) is only available on the Linux OS on the Pi.

Comment: Ok, those first steps worked but I still get the same error now, please see update 2

Comment: Check if the file has gone off the disk - that's a sign that the boot completed normally and ssh has been enabled.  Normally I use a file called 'ssh' (no extension) but I think ssh.txt should work.  If the file has gone then it points to the IP address being the wrong one.  You will need to look at your home router to see what address the PI has been given.

Comment: Had to unplug and replug the pi , now it works, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Normally you would SSH to the Pi and issue the command on the Pi not on Windows.

You may need to [install PuTTY](https://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/%7Esgtatham/putty/) on Windows first.